# Why do I see one more thread than the number I created in my `ps` listing?

Tags: linux, multithreading

When I create a thread (`pthread_create()`) from my main process, I see three (3) threads in the `ps` listing, why is this? That is, I see the process for the main thread, one for the created thread, and third for something else.  ***What is the something else?***  Everything works just fine, I'm just wondering what the extra listed process is.

```
~/ cat test.c
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
static          pthread_t       thread;
void * test_thread(void * ptr)
{
    sleep(30);
    return(ptr);
}
void thread_init(void)
{
     if (pthread_create( &thread , NULL, test_thread, NULL))
          perror("Thread not created!");
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    thread_init();
    sleep(30);
}
```

When I execute this code on a system running Linux 2.6.14 and BusyBox (but using bash 2.04g), the `ps` listing I get after rebooting and launching my test program above:

```
...
   52 root            SW  [kswapd0]
  667 root            SW  [mtdblockd]
  710 root            SWN [jffs2_gcd_mtd4]
  759 root        980 S   /bin/sh
  760 root        500 S   /bin/inetd
  761 root        516 S   /bin/boa
  762 root        644 S   /sbin/syslogd -n
  763 root        640 S   /sbin/klogd -n
  766 root       1516 S   /bin/sshd -i
  767 root       1036 S   -sh
  768 root        420 S   ./test
  769 root        420 S   ./test
  770 root        420 S   ./test
  771 root        652 R   ps
```

The kernel is a 2.6.14 kernel with a few added drivers modules.

Comment: And how are you creating the threads? With `pthread_create` or is that you think `fork` creates threads?

Comment: Guys voting to close, this is not off topic, it's just badly presented. Give the guy a chance to provide more information and maybe this would turn out to be a good question.

Comment: Source code and programming language, or we cannot help.

Comment: Vote for close because question is still to vague without any source code.

Comment: How are you issuing the ps command? In mine, I don't see the owner or those S/R flags (using `ps -A`). Also, are you on a standard kernel or did you compile yours?

Comment: To make sure you actually get three processes, restart your computer, run your program once and see if there are still three processes. If there is only one, it means that your previous runs of `test-d` were not cleanly finished.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Rebooted and clean launch ... still 3 processes, or that is to say always one more process than the number of threads I've (thought I've) launched.  The consecutively numbered PIDs support that (I would think).

Comment: Attach to the program with gdb and you can see what the threads are doing, to start with. The syntax is `gdb /path/to/test <PID>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely the "thread manager" thread.  See answer D.5 at this [link](http://gallium.inria.fr/~xleroy/linuxthreads/faq.html#D).

You won't see the extra process listed on most modern Linux systems if they are using NPTL.  But I searched and it sounds like BusyBox uses ulibc which I think only added NPTL support recently.  So I don't know for sure, but my guess is you are using LinuxThreads and seeing the manager thread as the extra thread.

Comment: Thanks.  A bit of a fiasco to get the answer, but you nailed it!

Comment: uClibc can be configured to use either NPTL or LinuxThreads implementations of POSIX threads. This can be seen if you run `make menuconfig` (from top level `General Library Support` --> `Thread Support`). **The git master branch of uClibc _still in year 2012_ says NPTL support is experimental**, warning of build problems, random damage, being potentially hazardous to your health and sanity. _"It will remain that way until further notice at which point this notice will disappear."_ Not very encouraging of choosing the non-obsolete and more correct pthread implementation...

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing one thread more than you are creating because you are not counting the programs main thread.

Every time you start a program, you fire up a process that has 1 thread running. If you `pthread_create` one thread, then you have *two* threads running. You `pthread_create` a second one and you get *three* threads running.

That is why your `ps` (which according to you on one of the comments) shows threads, is showing you one more than the number of your `pthread_create`s.

Comment: I should _not_ be allowed to post here on a Monday morning.  You definitely answered the question I _asked_.  Unfortunately, I've had to edit and ask the question I meant.  That is, I create one thread, in main() and I see the main() process, the thread process and one extra process.

Comment: Are there any libraries you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that ps is displaying 1 line for the process and 2 lines for both threads. You don't show how ps is being issued, what version, nor do you contain the entire about of the ps command.

ps typically shows only processes, not threads.

According to busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html the ps command will not show threads. ps -T will show threads. So if you are sure only ps is being issued (I don't know about alias in BusyBox or anything at all, I've never used it) then you are seeing 3 processes, not threads.

Also you may be using an old version of BusyBox? Refer to this bug report: bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=3835