# Why do I see one more thread than the number I created in my BusyBox `ps` listing?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I see one more thread than the number I created in my `ps` listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387623/why-do-i-see-one-more-thread-than-the-number-i-created-in-my-ps-listing)

When I create a thread (`pthread_create()`) from my main process, I see three (3) threads in the `ps` listing, why is this? That is, I see the process for the main thread, one for the created thread, and third for something else.  ***What is the something else?***  Everything works just fine, I'm just wondering what the extra listed process is.

```
~/ cat test.c
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
static          pthread_t       thread;
void * test_thread(void * ptr)
{
    sleep(30);
    return(ptr);
}
void thread_init(void)
{
     if (pthread_create( &thread , NULL, test_thread, NULL))
          perror("Thread not created!");
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    thread_init();
    sleep(30);
}
```

When I execute this code on a system running Linux 2.6.14 and BusyBox (but using bash 2.04g), the `ps` listing I get after rebooting and launching my test program above is:

```
...
   52 root            SW  [kswapd0]
  667 root            SW  [mtdblockd]
  710 root            SWN [jffs2_gcd_mtd4]
  759 root        980 S   /bin/sh
  760 root        500 S   /bin/inetd
  761 root        516 S   /bin/boa
  762 root        644 S   /sbin/syslogd -n
  763 root        640 S   /sbin/klogd -n
  766 root       1516 S   /bin/sshd -i
  767 root       1036 S   -sh
  768 root        420 S   ./test
  769 root        420 S   ./test
  770 root        420 S   ./test
  771 root        652 R   ps
```

There they are: three consecutively numbered PID processes.  It doesn't seem to be causing any harm, but I *am* curious.

Comment: The linked dupe already has a reply, so I'm voting to re-open that one and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that ps is displaying 1 line for the process and 2 lines for both threads.  You don't show how ps is being issued, what version, nor do you contain the entire about of the ps command.

ps typically shows only processes, not threads.

Comment: I type `~/$ ps` to get the ps listing shown.  `ps` on the system in question is implemented by BusyBox.

Comment: According to http://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html the ps command will not show threads.  ps -T will show threads.  So if you are sure only ps is being issued (I don't know about alias in BusyBox or anything at all, I've never used it) then you are seeing 3 processes, not threads.

Comment: Also you may be using an old version of BusyBox?  Refer to this bug report: https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=3835

Comment: That's it.  If you've answered in the other thread I'll give you check mark.

Comment: I've answered it in the other thread.  Thanks.