# Why does my program show more threads than created?

Tags: c, multithreading

I am working on a 32-core Intel cloud instance, and I want to use only 8 threads.  I use the following C program (thread_create_in_C) to create threads:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern void * Complex_Calc_YZ_fn();

int thread_create_in_C(numberOfProcessors) {

    pthread_t threads[numberOfProcessors];

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    cpu_set_t cpus;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcessors; i++) {
       CPU_ZERO(&cpus);
       CPU_SET(i, &cpus);
       printf("Core created %d\n", i);
       pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpus);
       pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, Complex_Calc_YZ_fn, NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcessors; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        printf("Core joined %d\n", i);
    }

    return numberOfProcessors;
}
```

The program is linked into and called from a larger program.  It's the only place where threads/cores are created and dispatched.  It has two output lines ("Core created" and "Core joined"), and the output confirms that only 8 threads are created.  Each thread is pinned to a core with pthread_attr_setaffinity_np.

My problem is that at various breakpoints in the calling program, I see "thread 9" or "thread 10" hit the breakpoint when I only created 8 threads (0-7).  Because the threads are dispatched when created, it's not possible to see thread numbers > 7 in the program it's dispatched to.

My questions are:

1. If a processor has more threads than I am using, can the thread number migrate even when it's pinned to a core?  In other words, could thread 6 migrate to thread 10, even if 6 is pinned to a core?  If so, is how can I prevent this behavior so I'm not confused about which thread I''m on?
2. If not, what else could explain why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't own all the threads in your process. Why do you care? You're only going to be doing work on your threads, which are pinned to whatever CPU you want, right? Mind, that sounds like a bad idea - why do you think you're better at assigning threads than the OS? Are you intending to identify which of the CPUs are real and which are virtual? Which are full-sized cores and which aren't? How throttling affects the performance of each individual core? How it all works with various power saving schemes? These things are complicated.

Comment: `libc` can create extra threads to do other things, you don't need to worry about them as they don't consume much cpu see also [Why do I see one more thread than the number I created in my `ps` listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387623/why-do-i-see-one-more-thread-than-the-number-i-created-in-my-ps-listing)

Comment: @Luuan - "why do you think you're better at assigning threads than the OS?"  If you don't pin a thread to a core it can migrate, and two threads could migrate to the same core, reducing their efficiency.  I pin threads to cores to be sure each thread uses a single CPU exclusively.  The box in question has 32 real cpus.  Power saving addresses performance, but my question is about thread numbers.

Comment: If you try passing different values to threads using a single variable for the last argument to `pthread_create()`, you end up with a race condition; it is not guaranteed that the thread has processed that data by the time `pthread_create()` returns.  In your code, you're using the same variable with different values for the attributes passed to `pthread_create()` — I wonder if you're running into a similar race condition?  I'm far from confident that it's a problem, but it might be something to check.  The attribute data is much more likely to be read before `pthread_create()` returns.

Comment: @RTC222 the OS scheduler typically migrates threads from busy cored to idle cores, not to from idle cores to busy ones.  The people designing the OS scheduler are very aware of the importance of maximizing performance :)